# having trouble with modeling use case diagram

Tags: content-management-system, uml, use-case

**Solved**

Ok, so i have a problem.

I need to model a use case diagram for a new CMS system. the point is, there is a "superAdmin" who can do all the same stuff as the client (buyer of the website) and more.

When I model this my Use case diagram turns into a spider web. And i'm guessing that isn't good.

Would there be any other good way to model this?

*Model:* ...

What could I do to make model this right?

And yes, almost everything is "Manage (beheer in dutch)". That is because a client want to CRUD almost everything of his website.

**Solution**

Generalization between actors.

For more information I suggest reading:

[Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409432.aspx)

[Modern Analyst](http://www.modernanalyst.com/Careers/InterviewQuestions/tabid/128/ID/360/What-is-actor-generalization.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

See also:

- [uml-diagrams.org: Relationships Between Actors](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/use-case-actor.html)

Comment: Thank you very much! 

didn't know this was possible

Comment: @Mr.wiseguy many of the things that are UML-possible can be found in [uml-diagrams.org: UML Diagrams Examples](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/index-examples.html). It is worth browsing (at least once)